# How to trigger jenkins job concurrently/per node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have created a Job named JobFoo, which takes parameter sleep. I am having 3 nodes with me nodeA,nodeB,nodeC and associated all with Lable JobFooRunner.
Any node can run a JobFoo only ones at a time.
So If I am triggered  JobFoo 4 times with parameter(sleep=1,2,3,4) at the same time. Then 3 jobs should be running parallelly on different nodes and 4th job should be in Queue. whenever any node is free it will run the last 4th job.

how can I achieve this, I have tried  "Node and Label parameter plugin",but it is running total 4*3=12 jobs.

Comment: You mean when you trigger a job it starts running 3 jobs on all 3 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it's not that clear what you're really want to achieve.
By default, when you queue several builds and there is no [`disableConcurrentBuilds`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options) option defined in your pipeline code, Jenkins will do what you've described.

If you want more capacity to run the builds in parallel, you can [increase the number of executors](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/nodes/) on each node. Be aware of the consequences though - with regard to both performance and stability because the build could use the same resources such as caches simultaneously.

If you want to trigger the same pipeline with 3 different sets of parameters in parallel, have a look at [`matrix`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) functionality, or define 3 stages within a [`parallel`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) block. The latter could also be done dynamically.

If you want to restrict the maximum count of concurrent builds per job to 3, you can define a [lockable resource](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#sidebar-content) with 3 as the max amount, and [`lock`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#lock-lock-shared-resource) that resource in your pipeline.